# Javascript shorthand way to duplicate strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, shorthand

I have this code in a function, and want to shorten it -  it applies the same style to every item in an array.

```
document.getElementById(divsArray[0]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById(divsArray[1]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById(divsArray[2]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById(divsArray[3]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

NO answer to date worked (Because I am looping thru the code??)

Resolved it by setting only the previously displayed slide visibility to hidden

```
x = i;
i = i+1;

document.getElementById(divsArray[x]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: Holy down votes, Batman!

Comment: all are copying the same answer on this question

Comment: @Amr: whether they're copying or not is unclear (it's an obvious answer, so probably not) but they don't add anything either and so should have been deleted.

Comment: Each answer is slightly different.  I don't think they're copying -- but it's a logical answer to put it in a for loop of some sort.  Plus, each answer is within seconds of each other.  That doesn't look like copying to me -- looks like everyone had the same suggestion.

Comment: @Shog9: But Rhys hasn't selected an answer.  Why should they delete an answer when the questioner hasn't selected an answer?

Comment: @DHoerster: why would you knowingly leave a duplicate answer around? Either edit to distinguish it in some way (as did sje397, sworoc) or remove it. Otherwise, it serves no purpose!

Comment: @Shog9: who died and made you the boss?

Comment: @rmeador: are you absolving yourself of responsibility?

Comment: @Shog9: This site is the free market at work -- everyone wants their answer to be selected.  So let's say that you and I both answered this question, and I used `for(var i=0;i<4;i++)` and you used `for(i=0;i<4;i++)`.  The answers are essentially the same, but slightly different.  If I answered 4 seconds ahead of you, would you delete your answer, **even** though you know you're more right than me?  That's why no one deleted their answers -- they're all slightly different, and they're leaving it up to Rhys to decide.

Comment: @Rhys: You didn't think your question would generate this kind of interaction, eh?  This is great!  :)

Comment: @DHoerster: Actually, yes - when I post an answer that doesn't add anything to what's already been posted, I'll either remove it or work to add something extra to it (in your example, I could hypothetically add an explicit declaration for `i` and go on to explain that I prefer this style because for(var... can be misleading to readers familiar with other languages where for introduces scope - but to leave the answer stand, assuming that a reader unfamiliar with looping will somehow *know* my reasoning, does more harm than good). And re: the free market: I'm participating in that market...

Comment: BTW: rather than dragging the discussion here too far off-topic, consider contributing to this question on Meta: [What’s the appropriate etiquette when two people correctly answer a question at the same time?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31513/whats-the-appropriate-etiquette-when-two-people-correctly-answer-a-question-at-t)

Comment: Gosh - what a turmoil!  I'm in a different time zone and came back to find all this.
I tried all the solutions, and they all freeze the function, or display only divsArray[0]

Should I post the entire code? Seems there must be some element in it that is creating a block.

Comment: @Rhys: at this point, if you're still encountering problems you might want to open a new question and post enough of the code to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: @Shog9'- Thanks
I eventually solved it myself by setting a value for divsArray[x] that hid the previous slide in the loop, instead of repeatedly setting every element in the array to 'hidden'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById(divsArray[i]).style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide something different, a jQuery solution:

```
$(divsArray).each(function() {
  $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Edit: It looks like you might have to collect your DOM references first. (divsArray is really just an array of div names, and not the divs themselves?)

```
$(divsArray).each(function() {
  $("#" + this).css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
});
```

Comment: Dude, you're asking for trouble with that answer.  This is a tough crowd!  :)  Check out the comments.  :)

Comment: @D Hoerster - ha ha, your not wrong I was just about to add a comment and the anwswer was deleted part way through! :)

Comment: if `divsArray` is all id strings, it should be `$('#'+this).css("visibility", "hidden"); ` right?

Comment: Yes, I added how I would do it to my answer for clarity.

Comment: I like this code because it is really short, and because it offers the possibility of varying the number of items in the array

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me that there might be more divs... Might I suggest this change to Darin's code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < divsArray.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById(divsArray[i]).style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

Comment: I like this on principle, though strictly-speaking it isn't necessarily a replacement for what the OP wrote.

Comment: I wouldn't use `divsArray.length` unless the OP explicitly says that he wants to use all the elements in the array. What if he wants only the first four elements? But it's a good point anyway.

Comment: @Darin OP does state every item in the array.

Answer (score 4):

And here's how it works in both [Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/) and [Mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/):

```
$(divsArray).each(function(item) {
  $(item).setStyle({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the following function in the same/descendant scope of divsArray.

```
function baka(idx) {
  document.getElementById(divsArray[idx]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Then you can do either

```
baka(0);
baka(1);
baka(2);
baka(3);
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  baka(i);
```

It looks pointless, but if you have more arrays like that, you may want to modify your function like this:

```
function aho(arr, idx) {
  document.getElementById(arr[idx]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

and loop through any array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < divsArray.length; i++)
  aho(divsArray, i);
```

And no, there are no macros nor are there templates.

Comment: Very creative, +1 for providing an interesting answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
  document.getElementById(divsArray[i]).style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

Comment: It's good style to declare your index variable *somewhere* (though not necessarily in the for() statement, since that doesn't create scope anyway) to avoid problems with globals. But Darin beat you to the punch this time... ;-)

Comment: "Beaten to the punch" by all of 4 seconds (according to what I saw when the page reloaded.  I didn't bother with deleting as I figured it reinforced the point that it was the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

as long as we're all piling on, i'll take the most direct approach :D

```
document.getElementById(divsArray[0]).style.visibility =
document.getElementById(divsArray[1]).style.visibility =
document.getElementById(divsArray[2]).style.visibility =
document.getElementById(divsArray[3]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

and just to go against the grain:

```
var d = null, i = 0;
while (d = document.getElementById(divsArray[i++])) {
    d.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't "resist" to the challenge. I would say you add them the same class and do something like (Prototype example):

```
$$('.className').invoke('setStyle', { 'visibility' : 'hidden' });
```

Comment: +1 for invoke, didn't think of that, but apart from that you are making assumptions (maybe there is not a common css class or maybe there is and it's also used by other components). So you must find a way to convert an array of ids to a map of elements first. My guess would be arrayOfIds.map($).invoke() but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate over array containing `id`s using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and ES6's [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var elemIds = ['two', 'four', 'six'];

elemIds.forEach(id => {document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';});
```

```html
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div>
<div id="five">Five</div>
<div id="six">Six</div>
<div id="seven">Seven</div>
```